# JavaScript object will not print

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I am trying to print out my object but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm very new to coding and am not sure as to what I am doing wrong here. Please help!

```
function Coffee(name, roast, location) {
    this.name = name;
    this.roast = roast;
    this.location = location;

    var esspresso = new Coffee("Starbuck's Esspresso Blend", "Dark", "Seattle");
    var cappuccino = new Coffee(coffee.name(espresso), "Dark", "Seattle");

    var CoffeeType = function() {
        return coffee.name + " " + coffee.roast + " from " + coffee.location;
    };
}
document.write(CoffeeType(cappuccino));
```

Comment: Have you tried checking for console errors?

Comment: `CoffeeType` doesn't exist where you are trying to access it. Did you mean to put the `}` after `this.location = location;` instead of before `document.write`? It doesn't make a lot of sense to call `Coffee` instead itself. `CoffeeType` also doesn't expect any argument and there is no variable with name `coffee`. Overall this seems to be arbitrarily stitched together. Which tutorial are you following? I suggest to read http://eloquentjavascript.net/ instead.

Comment: Have some literature on scope! http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: I'm not using a tutorial... Just trying to figure things out on my own... Thanks for the insight!

Comment: _"it doesn't seem to be working"_ is not a good enough problem statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're shooting for an object oriented approach, you should be defining your functions on the `prototype` chain.

```
function Coffee(name, roast, location) {
    this.name = name;
    this.roast = roast;
    this.location = location;
}

Coffee.prototype.getCoffeeType = function() {
    return this.name + " " + this.roast + " from " + this.location;
};

var esspresso = new Coffee("Starbuck's Esspresso Blend", "Dark", "Seattle");
var cappuccino = new Coffee(esspresso.name, "Dark", "Seattle");

document.write(cappuccino.getCoffeeType());
```

The code above will have the following effects:

- `function Coffee(...)` is the class's main constructor.
- `Coffee.prototype.getCoffeeType` is a function that each instance of the `Coffee` class will have.  This function will be able to access the `this` variables of the class (the class members).
- `esspresso` and `cappuccino` are instances of the `Coffee` class, instantiated somewhere in program code (outside of the class definition / constructor / prototype functions).
- You can then call functions defined on the class's prototype chain on these instance objects.
- The output of the above code will give you "Starbuck's Esspresso Blend Dark from Seattle"

Note that the additional benefit of defining a function on the `prototype` is that all instances will share the same `getCoffeeType` function instead of having a separate function (which does the same thing) on each instance.  (see [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870)).  If you're running a large coffee chain and producing millions of coffees, then you'll probably save a fair amount of resources (i.e. memory).

Comment: Wow! Thanks a ton for the deep explanation. You don't know how much I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

`CoffeeType` is defined only in the scope of `Coffee`, and can't be used outside of the `{` `}`. You also need to pass in the `coffee` as an argument to use it. `var CoffeeType = function( coffee ) {`.

Change your program to define `CoffeeType` in a higher scope so it can be used outside of `Coffee`'s body:

```
function CoffeeType(coffee) {
    return coffee.name + " " + coffee.roast + " from " + coffee.location;
};

function Coffee(name, roast, location) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function Coffee(name, roast, location) {

    this.name = name;
    this.roast = roast;
    this.location = location;
    this.CoffeeType = function() {
        return this.name + " " + this.roast + " from " + this.location;
    };

}

var esspresso = new Coffee("Starbuck's Esspresso Blend", "Dark", "Seattle");
var cappuccino = new Coffee("espresso", "Dark", "Seattle");

console.log(esspresso.CoffeeType())
```